# a form of "singular"/"plural"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Illegal trade in wildlife has become a sophisticated transnational form of **crime**, comparable to other pernicious examples, such as trafficking of drugs, humans, counterfeit items and oil.

OR

> 2. Illegal trade in wildlife has become a sophisticated transnational form of **crimes**, comparable to other pernicious examples, such as trafficking of drugs, humans, counterfeit items and oil.
>      ockquote

Which form of *crime* should I choose, singular or plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only your first sentence is grammatical.

If you want to use a plural version, it would look something like this:

> 2. Illegal ***trades*** in wildlife ***have*** become sophisticated transnational ***forms of crime***, comparable to other pernicious examples, such as trafficking of drugs, humans, counterfeit items and oil.

---

As for which you should use, that's up to you. Are you talking about the generic trade in wildlife (an uncountable mass noun), or specific countable instances of trade in wildlife?

---

To be more specific, when *form of* and *crime* are combined, without any intervening words, there are two possibilities:

> a form of crime
>   forms of crime

*Crime*, here, is an uncountable mass noun.

It *is* possible to construct a sentence like this:

> What was the form of ***the*** crimes?

But *crimes* (plural) is only used here because of the article in front of it and because *crime* is now being used as a countable noun.

Comment: dear Jason, you have solved  a much wider issue for me. But I am asking which form of noun is followed by "a form of", crime and crimes. It's all my fault, for I should have made clear everything.

Comment: @MikePhilip I've expanded my answer.